# POST запрос к api random.org на PHP

Tags: php, api, curl

Имеется следующий код. Проблема в том, что на странице не отображается ровным счётом ничего, то есть никакого результата вообще. Специально проверил - curl подключён.

```
<?php 

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.random.org/json-rpc/1/invoke');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{
                                            "jsonrpc": "2.0",
                                            "method": "generateIntegers",
                                            "params": {
                                                "apiKey": "4ea93cac-6bab-4e8d-b6ba-4c2f6e6ac942",
                                                "n": 10,
                                                "min": 1,
                                                "max": 123456789,
                                                "replacement": true
                                            },
                                            "id": 3
                                            }');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    $out = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $out;
    ?>
```

Comment: А вы вместо `echo $out;` сделайте `var_dump($out);` Плюс дополните код выводом ошибок курла.

Comment: Вставил таким образом
  $out = curl_exec($ch);
  echo curl_error ( $ch );
  curl_close($ch);
  echo $out;
  var_dump($out);                                                                                  Пишет SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failedbool(false)

Comment: проблема решена отключением SSL curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false). Спасибо за помощь